# see if a 2d collider is between 2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a fruit ninja sort of game where your mouse is a blade and you can cut items like fruit. So the fruit has a collider and so does the blade.

Problem is when you cut fast, the collider might move too fast to collide with the fruit.

To overcome this i need a way to see if a collider is between two points.

I can do this to get the 2 points;

```
vector 3 lastPos = Vector3.zero;

void Update()
{
    /*If collider between Input.mouse.position & lastPos {
        collided();
    }*/
    lastPos = Input.mouse.position;
}

void collided()
{
   ...
}
```

Is this possible to do and what would be the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Within blade:

```
private Vector3 bladeLastPos;

private void Start(){
    bladeLastPos = new Vector3(blade.position.x,blade.position.y,blade.position.z); 
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y);
    Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(bladeLastPos.x, bladeLastPos.y);
    float maxRange = Vector2.Distance(v1,v2);

    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(v1, v2 - v1, maxRange);

    for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
    {
        var component = hits[i].transform.GetComponent<ScriptNameInFruitWhereCutIs>();
        if (!component.cut)
        {
            //Cut! use public properties/functions within component
        }
    }
    bladeLastPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,transform.position.z); 
}
```

**This line will be a thin straight line between centers and not the full trace left by the entire blade shape.**

Comment: I edited the answer to provide the within-blade scalable solution, following your edit.